# fgetcsv/fputcsv $escape parameter fundamentally broken

Tags: php, csv

### Overview

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) support an `$escape` argument, however, it's either broken, or I'm not understanding how it's supposed to work. Ignore the fact that you don't see the `$escape` parameter documented on `fputcsv`, it is supported in the PHP source, there's a small bug preventing it from coming through in the documentation.

The function also supports `$delimiter` and `$enclosure` parameters, defaulting to a comma and a double quote respectively. I would expect the `$escape` parameter should be passed in order to have a field containing any one of those metacharacters (backslash, comma or double quote), however this certainly isn't the case. (I now understand from reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), these are to be enclosed in double-quotes).

### What I've tried

Take for example the pitfall that has affected numerous posters in the comments section from the `fgetcsv` documentation. The case where we'd like to write a single backslash to a field.

```
$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'w');
fwrite($r, '"\"');
fclose($r);

$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'r');
var_dump(fgetcsv($r));
fclose($r);
```

This returns `false`. I've also tried `"\\"`, however that also returns `false`. Padding the backslash(es) with some nebulous text gives `fgetcsv` the boost it needs... `"hi\\there"` and `"hi\there"` both parse and have the same result, but the result has only 1 backslash, so what's the point of the `$escape` at all?

I've observed the same behavior when not enclosing the backslash in double quotes. Writing a 'CSV' file containing the string `\`, and `\\`, have the same result when parsed by `fgetcsv`, **1** backslash.

Let's ask PHP how it might encode a backslash as a field in a CSV using `fputcsv`

```
$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($r, array('\\'));
fclose($r);
echo file_get_contents('/tmp/test.csv');
```

The result is a double-quote enclosed single backslash (and I've tried 3 versions of PHP > 5.5.4 when `$enclose` support was supposedly added to `fputcsv`). The hilarity of this is that `fgetcsv` can't even read it properly per my notes above, it returns `false`... I'd expect `fputcsv` not to enclose the backslash in double quotes or `fgetcsv` to be able to read `"\"` as `fputcsv` has written it..., or *really* in my apparently misconstrued mind, for `fputcsv` to write a double quote enclosed *pair* of backslashes and for `fgetcsv` to be able to properly parse it!

### Reproducible Test

Try writing a single quote to a file using `fputcsv`, then reading it via `fgetcsv`.

```
$aBackslash = array('\\');

// Write a single backslash to a file using fputcsv
$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($r, $aBackslash);
fclose($r);

// Read the file using fgetcsv
$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'r');
$aFgetcsv = fgetcsv($r);
fclose($r);

// Compare the read value from fgetcsv to our original value
if(count(array_diff($aBackslash, $aFgetcsv)))
  echo "PHP CSV support is broken\n";
```

### Questions

Taking a step back I have some questions

- What's the point of the `$escape` parameter?
- Given the loose definition of CSV files, can it be said PHP is supporting them *correctly*?
- What's the 'proper' way to encode a backslash in a CSV file?

### Background

I initially discovered this when a co-worker provided me a CSV file produced from Python, which wrote out a single backslash enclosed by double quotes and after `fgetcsv` failed to read it. I had the gaul to ask him if he could use a *standard* Python function. Little did I know the PHP CSV toolkit is a tangled mess! (FWIW: the Python dev tells me he's using the CSV writing module).

Comment: FWIW, the PHP string literal `'"\\"'` stands for the string `"\"`. If you want two backslashes in your string you need to write `'"\\\\"'`. I think half of your complaints about a single backslash is based on this misunderstanding, no?

Comment: These are characters in the CSV file, not in PHP code. PHP should interpret them based on the CSV format, not its internal string representation. Again, what is the purpose of the `$escape` argument in `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` then?

Comment: I did just clean up some of the single quotes in those strings that I'm trying to indicate are coming from the file. I'll grant you those were probably misleading.

Comment: `"\"` is invalid CSV. It means an opening enclosure, followed by a literal double quote character, without a terminating enclosure. Unfortunately, since reading your question and the answers, I've done some experimenting and I've discovered that, contrary to what you'd expect, the returned string is **not** unescaped. So, to encode a single backslash, the CSV needs to be `"\\"` (four characters, or `"\\\\"` in PHP code) which will return `\\`. It's then up to you to unescape the escape characters. It's actually not broken, but you have to realise how unintuitive it is first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a quick look at Python's documentation on [CSV Format Parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params), the escape character used within enclosed values (i.e. inside double quotes) is another double quote.

For PHP, the default escape character is a backslash *(^)*; to match Python's behaviour you need to use this:

```
$data = fgetcsv($r, 0, ',', '"', '"');
```

*(^) Actually `fgetcsv()` treats both `$enclosure||$enclosure` and `$escape||$enclosure` in the same way, so the `$escape` argument is used to avoid treating the backslash as a special character.*

*(^^) Setting the `$length` parameter to `0` instead of a fixed hard limit makes it less efficient.*

Comment: I don't think that's entirely accurate, and this is where the purpose of the `$escape` parameter is confusing. You see without specifying the `$escape` parameter, when you write a single double quote out to a file, php will output 3 double quotes. It's one of those details of the vague CSV spec, *double quotes are escaped with double quotes*. I've seen this mentioned in comments on php.net and wikipedia. This again begs the question of the `$escape` parameter, though, if a double quote is essentially a built in escape parameter, why have another one?

Comment: @quickshiftin Actually, `fgetcsv()` detects double enclosures by default, so the `$escape` argument is really to prevent it from treating the backslash as a special character.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense either, since the escape character will obviously be treated as a special character. If it isn't treated as a special character, that could be the problem right. But clearly the escape character **is** being treated specially, since it's placed within delimiters automatically via `fputcsv`.

Comment: Actually, your update has helped me to understand why the `fgetcsv` parser is breaking. It sees the opening double quote, but then doesn't see the closing one because it's escaped. This lends credence to my original thought `fputcsv` could be made smarter. Why write out something that knowingly **won't** be readable on the other side of the fence. It's an edge case, but I think it has merit.

Comment: @quickshiftin I didn't read the signature of `fgetcsv()` closely enough; the first argument is `$length` which I had missed earlier on, so I've updated that. It now decodes data properly, but I agree that the default `$escape` value of `fgetcsv()` should be changed to match the behaviour of `fputcsv()`.

Answer (score 4):

## EDIT 2

So after sleep and a relook at the code, turns out fputcsv doesn't accept the escape parameter, and I was being stupid. I've updated the code below to proper working code. The same basic principle applies, the escape parameter is there to alter the escape parameter so you can load a CSV with backslashes without them being treated as escape characters. The trick is to use a character that isn't contained within the csv. You can do this by grepping the file for a specific character, until you find one that isn't returned.

## EDIT

Ok, so the verdict is that it checks for the escape char, and then never stops checking. So, if it finds it, it's escaped. That simple.

That said, the purpose of the escape parameter is to allow for this exact situation, where you can alter the escape char to a character that isn't needed.

Here I've converted your example code to a working code:

```
$aBackslash = array('\\');

// Write a single backslash to a file using fputcsv
$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($r, $aBackslash, ',', '"'); // EDIT 2: Removed escape param that causes PHP Notice.
fclose($r);

// Read the file using fgetcsv
$r = fopen('/tmp/test.csv', 'r');
$aFgetcsv = fgetcsv($r, ',', '"', '#');
fclose($r);

// Compare the read value from fgetcsv to our original value
if(count(array_diff($aBackslash, $aFgetcsv)))
  echo "PHP CSV support is broken\n";
else
  echo "PHP WORKS!\n";
```

One important caveat is that both `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` *must* have the same parameters, otherwise the returned array will not match up to the original array.

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

You are very correct. This is a failing with the language. I've tried every permutation of slashes that I can think of, and I've yet to actually achieve a successful response from the CSV. It always returns just as your example says.

I think what @deceze was mention is that in your example you use `array('\\')` which is actually the string literal "\" which PHP interprets as such, and passes "\" to the CSV, which is then returned that way. This returns the erroneous response `\"`, which, as I stated above, is definitely wrong.

I did manage to find a work around, so that the result is actually appropriate:

First, for your example we'll either need to generate /tmp/test.csv in with "\" as the body, or alter the array slightly. Easiest method is just changing the array to:

```
array('"\\\\"');
```

After that, we should change up the fgetcsv request a bit.

```
$aFgetcsv = fgetcsv($r);
$aFgetcsv = array_map('stripslashes', $aFgetcsv);
```

By doing this, we're telling PHP to strip the first slash, thus making the string within $aFgetcsv "\"

Comment: Regarding the `array('\\')` from my example, I have done that on purpose. The point is to illustrate the `fputcsv` writes out the single backslash amidst surrounding double quotes. Trying to read that with `fgetscsv` fails, which is definitely a bug imo.

Comment: The other question still stands too, which is if things are more or less 'escaped' in a CSV by surrounding double quotes (or custom `$delimeter`), then what is the point of the `$escape` in the first place? Seems like nonsense to me. My guess is the bug is really on the `fgetcsv` side, since `fputcsv` seems to *'correctly'* surround the single backslash with double quotes. I've observed the same behavior from the Python CSV module (it writes a single backslash surrounded by double quotes).

Comment: My comment in the code even says "// Write a single backslash to a file using fputcsv"...

Comment: I agree that there's a bug in fgetcsv. I was simply explaining the confusion in the comments, and providing a workaround for this situation. I'd say submit a ticket to PHP. A friend of mine is already digging into the source, because you got him curious.

Comment: Cool, appreciate you taking a look at it. I've also taken a look a the source. There's definitely a bug in `fputcsv` preventing the `$escape` argument from showing in the documentation and on the CLI with `php --rf fputcsv`. Want to take a look at `fgetcsv` too, but so busy atm lol.

Comment: It's a huge function. I was able to confirm that the same glitch happens in str_getcsv, with the hillarious effect of `var_dump( str_getcsv('"\"') === str_getcsv('"\""') );` echoing `bool( true )`

Comment: Seems like it all boils down to the php_fgetcsv function, which both fgetcsv and str_getcsv calls

Comment: On top of the `fgetcsv` bug though, I'm still wondering what the point of `$escape` is. Seems like it could be removed entirely lol.

Comment: @quickshiftin I've added an edit to explain why this happens, and why it's not a bug, after reading more up on the code.

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is that the `$escape` character is off limits for inclusion as a field value using `fputcsv`/`fgetcsv`? If we take your example and use a *#* as the escape character, now we can't write a *#* character with `fputcsv` that can be read by `fgetcsv`. Just moves the original problem to a new character.

Comment: That's the basic issue with escape characters. There will always be breaking, if you have a file that contains all characters. The real solution is that you need to run my original suggestion: `array_map('stripslashes', $aFgetcsv);`

Comment: Also I've added another edit, as fputcsv doesn't actually accept escape as a parameter, which may be part of the confusion. Passing it with display_errors on shows a PHP notice.

Comment: There's a bug on `fpetcsv` like I was saying. The code is setup to support an `$escape` parameter, but there's a missing line in *ext/standard/basic_functions.c*. `+       ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, escape_char)`. I'll take a closer look at your answer tomorrow. Just too tired to give it proper attention today. Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: LOL `fpetcsv`, who's tired? The bug is in `fputcsv`. Once you add that line and recompile you'll see `php --rf fputcsv` on the command line starts behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. The solution was to set `$escape` to `false`:

```
$row = ['a', '{"b":"single dquote=\""}', 'c'];
fputcsv($f, $row);                // invalid csv: a,"{""b"":""single dquote=\"""}",c
fputcsv($f, $row, ',', '"', false); // valid csv: a,"{""b"":""single dquote=\""""}",c
```