# How to read a csv file with php code inside?

Tags: php, templates, csv

i searched Google but found nothing what fits for my problem, or i search with the wrong words.

In many threads i read, the smarty Template was the solution, but i dont wont use smarty because its to big for this little project.

My problem:

I got a CSV file, this file contents only HTML and PHP code, its a simple html template document the phpcode i use  for generating dynamic imagelinks for example.

I want to read in this file (that works) but how can i handle the phpcode inside this file, because the phpcode shown up as they are. All variables i use in the CSV file still works and right.

Short Version

how to handle, print or echo phpcode in a CSV file.

thanks a lot,

and sorry for my Bad english

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the CSV rows into strings, then replacing the <?php php_code(); ?> with a eval($phpCode)?

Comment: *"because the phpcode shown up as they are."* - Is your file a `.php` extension and is PHP running on the server you're on? @JayBlanchard *Gidday Sam*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answers. @Don Boots no i dont tried this, but it sounds good ... will try this

Comment: You should include examples of your CSV source.

Comment: Did a couple quick experiments, the fact that `fgetcsv` struggles with PHP content inside a CSV is just another fine example of the paltry CSV support PHP provides. I found [other issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840256/fgetcsv-fputcsv-escape-parameter-fundamentally-broken) a couple months ago myself. #disappointed...

Comment: `$userdatei = fopen("selltemplate/template.txt","r");
while(!feof($userdatei))
   {
   $zeile = fgets($userdatei);
   echo $zeile;
   }
fclose($userdatei);` so i read in the csv file 

and the content of csv file one line:

`src=&quot;&lt;?php echo $bild1; ?&gt;&quot; &gt;&lt;/a&gt;`

Comment: txt or csv have forgot to rename it sry

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your comment above you have the following code:

```
$userdatei = fopen("selltemplate/template.txt","r");

while(!feof($userdatei)) {
   $zeile = fgets($userdatei);
   echo $zeile;
}

fclose($userdatei);

// so i read in the csv file and the content of csv file one line:
// src=&quot;&lt;?php echo $bild1; ?&gt;&quot; &gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

This is assuming `$bild1` is defined somewhere else, but try using these functions in your `while` loop to parse and output your html/php:

```
$userdatei = fopen("selltemplate/template.txt","r");

while(!feof($userdatei)) {
   $zeile = fgets($userdatei);
   outputResults($zeile);
}

fclose($userdatei);

//-- $delims contains the delimiters for your $string. For example, you could use <?php and ?> instead of &lt;?php and ?&gt;
function parseString($string, $delims) {
    $result = array();

    //-- init delimiter vars
    if (empty($delims)) {
        $delims = array('&lt;?php', '?&gt;');
    }

    $start = $delims[0];
    $end = $delims[1];

    //-- where our delimiters start/end
    $php_start = strpos($string, $start);
    $php_end = strpos($string, $end) + strlen($end);

    //-- where our php CODE starts/ends
    $php_code_start = $php_start + strlen($start);
    $php_code_end = strpos($string, $end);

    //-- the non-php content before/after the php delimiters
    $pre = substr($string, 0, $php_start);
    $post = substr($string, $php_end);

    $code_end = $php_code_end - $php_code_start;
    $code = substr($string, $php_code_start, $code_end);

    $result['pre'] = $pre;
    $result['post'] = $post;
    $result['code'] = $code;

    return $result;
}

function outputResults($string) {
    $result = parseString($string);

    print $result['pre'];
    eval($result['code']);
    print $result['post'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having PHP code inside a `CSV` file that should be parsed and probably executed using `eval` sounds pretty dangerous to me.

If I get you right you just want to have dynamic parameters in your CSV file right? If thats the case and you don't want to implement an entire templating language ( like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) ) into your application you could do a simple **search and replace** thing.

```
$string = "<img alt='{{myImageAlt}}' src='{{myImage}}' />";

$parameters = [
    'myImageAlt' => 'company logo',
    'myImage' => 'assets/images/logo.png'
];

foreach( $parameters as $key => $value )
{
    $string = str_replace( '{{'.$key.'}}', $value, $string );
}
```